# Can Shudras attain Moksha?

Tags: moksha, reference-request, shudra

I have seen the verse in the Bhagavad Gita which says that Shudras women etc. can achieve the highest reality or state which is Moksha by taking refugee in him,so is there any more such verses that say that a Shudra can attain Moksha?

Comment: Yes there are. There are even examples to the effect.

Comment: @Adiyarkku Could you please site some of them, sir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Phalashruti section of [Sri Vishnusahasranama](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/vishnu/Sri.Vishnu.Sahasaranam.pdf) it is mentioned that one who takes refuge of the Supreme will attain eternal Brahman or liberation (*moksha*).

> ***vāsudevāśrayō martyō vāsudevaparāyaṇaḥ,***
>
> ***sarvapāpaviśuddhātmā yāti brahma sanātanam.*** (10)
>
> A mortal who takes refuge in Vāsudeva and is devoted to Vāsudeva,
> purified of all sins, attains to the eternal Brahman.

It is also mentioned that by reciting the thousand holy names of Lord Vishnu, a sudra can become happy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Sudras can attain moksha.

> In different ages many beings with Rajas and Tamas predominating in
> them - Asuras, Rakshas, beasts, birds, Gandharvas, Apsaras, serpents,
> Siddhas, Charanas, Guhyakas, Vidyadharas, and among human beings,
> unqualified persons like **women, Vaisyas, Sudras and outcastes** - all
> have attained to My being by the power of holy association alone.
> .....

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.12.3-7**

**Women and Sudras need help to attain moksha**

> But ignorant persons like women and the **Sudras**, who have had no
> facilities to hear about the Lord’s excellences and take His name,
> deserve to be pitied (and helped) by personages like you.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.5.4**

The above verse indirectly accepts that socially oppressed people like women and Sudras can attain moksha. If they could not attain moksha then no human help will suffice.

Comment: Is there any more such statements from the scriptures sir?

Comment: @Rajam, I know of another statement that indirectly supports the idea that Shudras can attain moksha. I will add that verse to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Shudras can attain Moksha even according to other texts. These other texts have been highlighted by the great ones who wrote answers to my question. And my intention here is to add to the verses. Shudras can gain Moksha by devotion to Shiva this is said in the Shiva Gita, the verse reads:

> 20. Without respect, or with deceit, Or in jest or by creating a false impression, If one were to still be devoted to Shiva, **Even if a Shudra, one would attain liberation**.

You can find this in chapter 1 verse 20.